# Accessing GKE resources from cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-vpc

I am trying to access GKE resource from a cloud function which is not happening and expected as well.

Trying to setup the Serverless VPC to achieve this . However its giving the error discussed in the https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/164378672?pli=1 .

Any other solution that helps here.

Comment: Could you please add as much detail as possible without linking to external resources. Some of the external issue hints may be applicable to your problem while others may be totally misleading...

Comment: @tmarwen., Okay . While creating the serverless VPC getting the below error. Do you have any idea how to resolve this.? or any other alternate solution to communicate between Cloud function to GKE.

"status": { "code": 13, "message": "An internal error occurred: Failed to create a VPC Access connector. Please delete the connector manually." },

Comment: Internal error means something went wrong with the platform, you have 2 options if you have support open a ticket, if you don't then open a new issuetracker as above.

Comment: No @WytrzymałyWiktor., i have anyways updated the support ticket but didnt help much.

Comment: If the related issue on Public Issue Tracker hasn't been resolved yet, please track it for updates. Probably this is the first place where you should look for the answer if this is the common problem, which was also reported by other users.